# C++: How do I cast an int to an unsigned long and not change any bits?

Tags: c++, casting, bit-manipulation

C++: How do I cast an int to an unsigned long and not change any bits?
I want to pack and unpack values into memory. The word size is 64 bits.

This snippet illustrates the problem:

```
int v1 = -2; // 0xfe
unsigned long v2=(unsigned long)v1; // 0xfffe, I want 0x00fe
```

The simple solution is:

```
unsigned long v2=(unsigned int)v1; // 0x00fe
```

However, this code is in a template where the target type is a parameter, so I had to resort to this:

```
uint64 target = mem[index] & mask;
uint64 v;
if (value < 0) {
    switch (bits) {
    case 8:
        v = (uint8)value;
        break;
    case 16:
        v = (uint16)value;
        break;
    case 32:
        v = (uint32)value;
        break;
    }
} else {
    v = value;
}
v = v << lShift;
target |= v;
mem[index] = target;
```

Assume, for example, the type for "value" is an int (16 bits) and bits=16.
The goal is to mask the bits in memory for value and replace them.

Does anyone know an easier way?

Comment: You have a word size of 64 bits and an int is 16?  That's special.

Comment: What is the method signature? You give only partial information thus only expect a partially good solution. But I suspect you can use boost::type_traits to help.

Comment: The way you do it is not portable. If you want to preserve the bits portably, you need to resort to type punning: `unsigned long v2= *(unsigned int*)&v1;`. Otherwise you get a *value conversion* which is allowed to change bits depending on the sign representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the idea put forth by "Kerrek SB" I came up with a solution.

```
template <typename Tint> uint64 ToMemdata(Tint value) {
    return (uint64)value;};
template <> uint64 ToMemdata<int8>(int8 value) {
    return (uint64)((uint8)value);};
template <> uint64 ToMemdata<int16>(int16 value) {
    return (uint64)((uint16)value);};
template <> uint64 ToMemdata<int32>(int32 value) {
    return (uint64)((uint32)value);};
template <> uint64 ToMemdata<int64>(int64 value) {
    return (uint64)((uint64)value);};

template <typename Tint> void packedWrite(Tint value, int vectorIndex, uint64* pData) {

    uint64 v = ToMemdata(value);
    // This call eliminates a run time test for minus and a switch statement
    // Instead the compiler does it based on the template specialization

    uint64 aryix, itemofs;
    vectorArrayIndex(vectorIndex, &aryix, &itemofs); // get the memory index and the byte offset
    uint64 mask = vectorItemMask(itemofs); // get the mask for the particular byte
    uint64 aryData = pData[aryix]; // get the word in memory
    aryData &= mask; // mask it
    uint64 lShift = (uint64)(itemofs * sizeof(Tint) * 8); 
    uint64 d = v << lShift; // shift the value into the byte position
    aryData |= d; // put the value into memory
    pData[aryix] = aryData;
}
```

Using this concept I was able to make other improvements to the code. 
For example, the call to vectorItemMask() is now templateized also.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you have C++0x support:

```
#include <type_traits>
v= static_cast<std::make_unsigned<decltype(value)>::type>(value);
```

I'm assuming that you are parameterizing on the type of `value`, otherwise this doesn't make any sense.

EDIT: making it more C++-ish by using `static_cast` instead of a C cast. I suppose that's what got me a downvote.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind the typing, a trait class comes to mind:

```
template <typename IType> struct ToULong;

template <> struct ToULong<signed char>
{
  static inline unsigned long int get(signed char c) { return (unsigned char)(c); }
};

template <> struct ToULong<signed short int>
{
  static inline unsigned long int get(signed short int c) { return (unsigned short int)(c); }
};

/* ... signed int, signed long int, signed long long int ... */
```

Usage:

```
template <typename IType>
struct Foo
{
  unsigned lont int get_data() const { return ToULong<IType>::get(m_data); }
private:
  IType m_data;
}
```

**Update:** Even simpler, you could just make a bunch of overloads:

```
unsigned long int toULong(            char c) { return (unsigned      char)(c); }
unsigned long int toULong(signed      char c) { return (unsigned      char)(c); }
unsigned long int toULong(signed short int c) { return (unsigned short int)(c); }
unsigned long int toULong(signed       int c) { return (unsigned       int)(c); }
unsigned long int toULong(signed  long int c) { return (unsigned  long int)(c); }
```

**2nd update:** You should probably say `static_cast<T>(x)` rather than `(T)(x)` if you want to be even more C++-like.

Comment: This looks really promising since the compiler is doing the work that my example does at runtime. So instead of the phrase "if (value < 0)" I'll add "v = ToULong<IntType>(value);" where "IntType" the the type for the value variable.

Comment: You need to call the static member function, `ToULong<IntType>::get(value)` -- but I think the overloaded free functions should work just as well and they're a little simpler conceptually. The trait class gives you some extra type safety though, because the free functions might also work for (unambiguously) implicitly convertible types, which may be unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

How about union?

```
union u1 {
    short int si;
    unsigned long int uli;

    unsigned long int stub;

    operator unsigned long int () {return uli;};
public:
    u1(short int nsi) : stub(0) {si = nsi;}

};
```

Comment: If sizeof(int) != sizeof(long int) then the top bits of the unsigned long might be undefined.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis Please note `stub` member.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you could use a bitwise-AND to get the desired result.

```
unsigned long v2 = 0;
v2 = v2 | v1;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be bitwise or? That's always going to yield 0.

Comment: And you would still get a promotion to a common type **before** doing the op.

Answer (score -1):

To cast without changing bits, take a reference and then dereference with appropriate type:

```
int v1 = -2; // 0xfe
unsigned long v2=*(unsigned long *)&v1;
```

This assumes the sizes are the same.  It has undefined behavior if sizeof(int) != sizeof(unsigned long).  You probably want unsigned int.

Edit: realized i answered wrong question.

Boost type_traits has something (i believe it is make_unsigned) to convert an int type to the unsigned version (if it is signed) and do nothing if it is unsigned.

Comment: Casting  `int*` to `unsigned long*` and dereferencing is undefined behaviour if I remember correctly.

Comment: With some compilers, int and unsigned long have the same size, which means there's no undefined behavior.  This is perfectly analogous to a union.

Comment: @Foo - Except that it breaks strict aliasing rules. Accessing one type through a pointer to another type **is** UB.

Comment: @Bo is *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long *>&v1 UB?

Comment: @Foo - The reinterpret_cast would have to be implementation defined. Otherwise we don't know what it does. The standard leaves casting between different pointer types up to the implementation.